# How to list the threads along with it's appropriate function in GDB.?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gdb

With the help of "info thread" command I can able to know the thread id and currently executing thread.When I have one or two threads can able to remind the function of each thread.Based on that I can able to execute the thread which I want.But when I'm working with multiple threads and I want to execute one particular function for that I need to remember all the function so that I can give the appropriate thread id to execute.It is impossible to remind all the threads along with it's function name.So,Is there any way to list the threads along with it's function name in GDB.?.

Thank You..!!.

Answer (score 3):

I press Ctrl+L to clear the screen buffer

```
set height 0
thread apply all bt
```

This will dump backtrace for all the threads but won't pause (because we set the window height to 0) if the list is long. I then copy/paste the output to a text editor for examination.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `thread apply all bt` command. It will print backtraces of all your threads. You will find thread function name inside each of these backtrace near the end and before `clone` system call.

Comment: "thread apply all bt" command will display only the function name of currently executing thread.What I want is all the threads with each of it's function name.

Comment: @Ravichandran.GES, No it should display all backtraces. Probably, you have only 1 thread when you are looking backtraces. What is the output of `info threads` ?

Comment: ,No I'm creating 3 threads.Info threads shows 3 thread information and it displays the function name of only one thread.For other threads it's not showing the name.output as follows                                                           (gdb) info thread
[New Thread 0xb75feb40 (LWP 17418)]
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  3    Thread 0xb75feb40 (LWP 17418) "a.out" 0xb7ef0d28 in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
* 2    Thread 0xb7dffb40 (LWP 17417) "a.out" print () at thread.c:15
  1    Thread 0xb7e006c0 (LWP 17416) "a.out" 0xb7ef0d28 in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Answer (score 0):

Found some links.They seem helpful :

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Debugging_with_gdb/threads.html
- http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multithreaded-debugging-techniques/199200938?pgno=6